# Using --noparse with browserify rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, browserify, browserify-rails

I am using [browserify-rails](https://github.com/browserify-rails/browserify-rails) gem in my Rails application. I am facing performance issue while development as any change takes 10 secs to load upon refresh. I went though [this thread](https://github.com/browserify-rails/browserify-rails/issues/43) and found out:

> browserify supports a noparse option -- configuring

and as suggested further:

> Could do noparse on everything in vendor/bundle.

which makes complete sense. However there is no example on how to do this and this is where I am having trouble. I tried adding following line to my `config/application.rb`:

```
config.browserify_rails.commandline_options = "--noparse=\"jquery-1.11.3.min.js\""
```

which resulted to this error:

> Uncaught Error: BrowserifyRails::BrowserifyError: Error while running
>   `/home/shivam/git/app/node_modules/.bin/browserifyinc
>   --noparse="jquery-1.11.3.min.js" --cachefile=\"/home/shivam/git/app/tmp/cache/browserify-rails/browserifyinc-cache.json\"
>   -o "/home/shivam/git/app/tmp/cache/browserify-rails/output20151109-8114-8rk552"
>   -`:

being completely new to ES6 I cannot understand what this error means. I am not even sure if I am using the `--noparse` option correctly. Can someone please provide me an example?

Comment: Please try browserify-rails v2 -- there should be performance improvements as we are now taking advantage of more aggressive caching from sprockets.